# Help with Metadata not working

Tags: nft, meta-data

I've been playing with trying to mint NFTs partly for my own learning, and partly because I'd like to NFT my company's public memos/docs to make accountability to my investors as easy as pointing to a contract, or even minting directly to their wallets. (hypothetical atm)

I am using the Remix IDE and OpenZeppelin's contracts, trying to mint ERC-1155s on polygon.

I have deployed a contract, and have minted NFTs to it, and at present, I'm trying to get my NFTs to have a description that shows up in opensea or looksrare for easy viewing, as well as an image.

The most recent attempt:
https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x54b48f756e924f0d32cc7ca3f1d0670268703a7c/0

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken5 is ERC1155, Ownable {

    constructor()
    ERC1155("ipfs://bafkreidefb4epyhswlzxfdrcbk2uxmttbbkempl7fk2djpf5cbpcdmdara")
{}

function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyOwner {
    _setURI(newuri);
}

function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    _mint(account, id, amount, data);
}

function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
}
```

}

IPFS hash of metadata:  bafkreidefb4epyhswlzxfdrcbk2uxmttbbkempl7fk2djpf5cbpcdmdara

IPFS hash of image: (called in metadata under "image") bafkreidefb4epyhswlzxfdrcbk2uxmttbbkempl7fk2djpf5cbpcdmdara

As the name "mytoken5" implies, I've tried this a few ways, most recently using Remix's setURI function with the same hash pointing to the JSON.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple and dumb, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I have switched to using HashLips' method on his channel where he mints "Daniel", and I'm still not having any luck. I've switched from nft.storage to pinata, from using the hash as the file directly to uploading a folder, referencing the folder hash and file name, and I've done a new contract, flattened, compiled, verified on polygonscan, and sent the TokenURI through polygonscan... I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem but on the Songbird Network.